# send select value failed

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm sending information to the laravel back request with a form but the info of this hidden javascript input doesn't arrive. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
JS

```
var selectName = $('select').attr('name');
// add a hidden element with the same name as the select
var hidden = $('');
hidden.val($('select').val());
hidden.insertAfter($('select'));
$("select option").unwrap().each(function() {
    var btn = $('' + $(this).text() + '');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) btn.addClass('on');
    $(this).replaceWith(btn);
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
    $('.btn').removeClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $('input\[name="' + selectName + '"\]').val($(this).text());
});
```

HTML BLADE
<select name="risposta">

SI
NO

thanks a lot in advance for the replies your text`your text`.

Comment: I'm not seeing how `hidden` has the same name as `select`; I *do* see where you set `hidden`'s value to the same value as `select`. Form fields without names don't get submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery works without warnings if you create strange jQuery sets like from a string as you did.
First you should create your hidden input right:

```js
const $select = $('select').on('change', () => {

  const $hidden = $('<input>', {
    type: 'hidden', 
    name: $select.attr('name')
  })
  .insertAfter($select)
  .val($select.val());
  alert(`${$hidden.attr('name')}: ${$hidden.val()}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test">
  <option value="">Select me</option>
  <option value="hidden-value">Hidden value</option>
</select>
```